# How to pick certain number of samples randomly from multiple samples in the API request using Jmeter

Tags: api, loops, jmeter, scripting

API body contains multiple samples. I need to pick randomly from 1 to 6 samples for each run.
How can I acheive this?
Does adding loop inside the API body, impacts the performance of the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can put different "bodies" to different files and read them using [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md#directory-listing-config), the file content can be read using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)

I don't think you can do the "looping" in the "API body", you can generate a random number of "samples" using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like it's described in [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html#_jsonbuilder) chapter of Groovy documentation. It won't impact "the performance of the API" but it will create an overhead and extra resources usage on JMeter side so you will be able to conduct lesser load from the same hardware.